# Matlab mex “Missing dependent shared libraries”

Tags: matlab, psychtoolbox

We have done some program with psych toolbox and we had no problems but recently we have some error due to mex.files and we did some suggestion from your site but it did not work and yet error is remained.

We checked by pursuit eyelinl Demo to know whether our codes have problems or not.

In The pursuit eye link Demo error we have had these errors:

```
Invalid MEX-file
'C:\toolbox\Psychtoolbox-3-PTB_Beta-2019-09-26_V3.0.16\Psychtoolbox\PsychBasic\MatlabWindowsFilesR2007a\Eyelink.mexw64':
Missing dependent shared libraries:
'eyelink_core64.dll' required by
'C:\toolbox\Psychtoolbox-3-PTB_Beta-2019-09-26_V3.0.16\Psychtoolbox\PsychBasic\MatlabWindowsFilesR2007a\Eyelink.mexw64'
'icudt61.dll' required by 'C:\Program Files\Polyspace\R2019a/bin/win64\icuuc61.dll->C:\Program
Files\Polyspace\R2019a/bin/win64\icuin61.dll->C:\Program
Files\Polyspace\R2019a/bin/win64\libmwi18n.dll->C:\Program
Files\Polyspace\R2019a/bin/win64\libmx.dll->C:\toolbox\Psychtoolbox-3-PTB_Beta-2019-09-26_V3.0.16\Psychtoolbox\PsychBasic\MatlabWindowsFilesR2007a\Eyelink.mexw64'

Error in pursuit/cleanup (line 374)
        Eyelink('Shutdown');

Error in pursuit (line 366)
    cleanup;
```

We are working with eye tracker but without connecting to it, yet we have above errors.

Comment: Are you saying that you used this demo before without problems? On the same computer with the same installation of MATLAB? What has changed? Can you reproduce this error? If so, please share the steps others can follow to reproduce it, otherwise there is no way to help.

Comment: From the error, it looks like the EyeLink API / SDK isn't configured properly. Have you downloaded the SDK from SR Research?